# Compare a few columns of one matrix against the column of another matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

Here I have created a duplicate data set.

```
set.seed(1234)
m1 = matrix(runif(2000), nrow = 10, ncol = 200)
dim(m1)
[1]  10 200
m2 = matrix(runif(100), nrow = 10, ncol = 10)
dim(m2)
[1] 10 10
```

I want to compare the first `1:20` columns of `m1` against the `1st column` of  `m2` matrix. Similarly, for the next `21:40` columns of  `m1` against the `2nd column` of  `m2` matrix and so on. Finally, `181:200` columns of matrix `m1` against the `10th` column of matrix `m2`.

I wrote the following code to compare `1st` `20` columns of `m1` matrix against the `1st` column of `m2` matrix.

```
cc = matrix(NA, nrow(m2), ncol(m2))
for (j in 1:ncol(m2)) {
  for (i in 1:nrow(m2)) {
    cc[i, j] = ifelse(m1[i, j] < m2[i,1], 1, 0)
  }
}
ccvalue = data.frame(cc)
```

How can I improve the above `r code` do the above comparison. Are there any `r` function to do?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the implicit vectorization in R to run the entire matrix of m1 against the columns of m2. You just need to get m2 to repeat columns by subsetting for the same column over and over again. For example, `v <-c("A","B","C")` you can do `v[c(1,1,2,2,3,3)]` which equals `"A","A","B","B","C","C"`.

Test out the following code and let me know if you have any questions:

```
# we want to compare m1[,c(1,2,3,...)], with m2[,c(1,1,1,...)]
# summing 1,0,...,1,0,... to get 1,1,...,2,2,...
m2_to_compare <- cumsum(rep(c(1,rep(0,19)),10)) 
# length should match m1 columns
length(m2_to_compare) 
(m1 < m2[,m2_to_compare]) * 1 # turns TRUEs and FALSEs into 1s and 0s
```

**Answering Comment:**

```
cc = ifelse(m1 < m2[,m2_to_compare], 1, 0)
# depending on your seed:
sapply(1:10, function(colm) rowSums(cc[,m2_to_compare == colm]))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    3    1   19    8    9   11   17    2   12    16
# [2,]    2   19   14   10   10   11    9    1    0    14
# [3,]   16   16   17    7    5   20    1   16    2    17
# [4,]   13    2    0   11   20   11    6    5   12     2
# [5,]    0   10    2    1   10   17    3   14    5     7
# [6,]   11    7   17    9   20   18   18   16    7     4
# [7,]   15    3    5    5    8    5    3    3    9     1
# [8,]    0   18    5    8    9   15    9   17    0    20
# [9,]   15   14    5    1    5    0    6   17   19     6
#[10,]    6    1    4   10   11   12    0    9    7     5
```

Comment: glad I could help

Comment: I have one more questions.I used the above way to compare the columns `cc = ifelse(m1 < m2[,m2_to_compare], 1, 0)`. I found the `rowSum` of first `20` columns `cc_sum = rowSums(cc[,1:20])`. How can I find the `rowSums` of next `20` columns and so on for all `10` sets of columns. Thanks again.

Comment: see my edit and let me know if that is what you are looking for

Comment: you can put a `which` around `m2_to_compare == colm` to see that we are just cycling through the columns you are interested in row summing together.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to point out:

(1) It would be a good practice to set the seed for matrix `m2` as well. Perhaps you overlooked that.

(2) In your code provided, you seem to be only comparing `m2` to the first `10` columns of `m1`.

If you only mean to compare the 10 columns, you can do it with this:

```
cc <- (m2 > m1[, c(1:10)])*1
```

Comment: @score324 No problem. :)